# Blank Screen when running CGIHTTPServer with python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm using Raspberry 3 and followed a tutorial on PluralSight. When running the following script I only get a blank screen.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
print 'Content-Type:text/html'
print
print '<html><body><h1>Hello from Python - '
print sys.version
print '</h1></body></html>
```

I saved the file in a cgi-bin folder, made it executable and run it with the following command

```
python -m CGIHTTPServer 8001
```

On the Raspberry Chromium browser I then type

```
localhost:8001/cgi-bin/test.cgi
```

All I get is a blank page.

I also tried the version described in the tutorial for python3, but this also only displays a blank page.

Anyone any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blank pages almost always mean that you have an error, usually in your script. The other common thing to see is an message stating "The server has encountered an error" or similar.

In your case, you may be missing a single quote at the end of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print 'Content-Type:text/html'
print 
print '<html><body><h1>Hello from Python - '
print sys.version
print '</h1></body></html>'
```

You should also try running the script normally to see if there are any other errors. Some servers will also log basic failure information (such as line number or server specific errors) in their error logs.

Comment: You're right, silly me. I stared at the script for ages and never noticed the missing quote.  Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem. =)